# Facebook Ads v2.1: Graph Explorer - Ads Manager UI "Campaign Group" edge discrepancy

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

if I navigate to the Campaign Group stats edge https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/539923059395125/?method=GET&path=6008937476954%2Fstats%2F1409544000%2F1409630400%3Ffields%3Dspent%2Cid%2Ccampaign_group_id%2Cclicks&version=v2.1 (or 6008937476954/stats/1409544000/1409630400?fields=spent,id,campaign_group_id,clicks in the graph explorer), I get:

```
"spent": 2722670, 
"campaign_group_id": "6008937476954", 
"clicks": 100557
```

This is a spend of $27,226.70.

If I navigate to the matching Account stats edge (act_1376129679277116/stats/1409544000/1409630400) in the Graph Explorer, it returns $1,099.61 which is correct (as is the Ad Sets stats edge). So it seems that just the Campaign group edge is (very) incorrect.

Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: @WizKid no need, it was already raised March 14th: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/254977514673678/  Shame it hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: why was this question downvoted?  Harsh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a long-standing known issue to FB: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/254977514673678/  No ETA as yet.